# Match only whitespace after a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace every whitespace after combination `*whitespace*[w OR i]` with number `0` using Javascript and RegEx.

**Example:**

This sentence:

`Somethingi i somethingw else w another thing.`

Should look like this:

`Somethingi i0somethingw else w0another thing.`

I know that in RegEx is something like `look behind` which would come in handy but unfortunately, this won't work with JavaScipt's version of RegEx. I'm looking for specific RegEx formula or clever way to do this in JS.

Comment: Could you please show what you tried exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The correct answer to my problem was posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(\s[iw])\s
```

and replace with `$10`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5ULjU7/2

```js
console.log( "Somethingi i somethingw else w another thing.".replace(/(\s[iw])\s/g, '$10'));
```